# How to limit voltage to equal or less than 6 volts for MCP1826 Vin?

Tags: solar-cell, esp32, ldo

Voltage from solar panel could exceed the 6 volt maximum Vin specification of the MCP1826-3302 LDO.  How can voltage be kept below Vin maximum specification?

[MCP1826 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22057B.pdf)

How should the PWRGD pin be terminated if not used?

The solar panel has not been ordered.  I'm looking at using a 6 or 10 watt solar panel.  This is my first ESP32 deep sleep, solar project. I will make calculations prior to ordering.

Credit for power path goes to Andreas Spiess for his "YouTube" video #383.

[image: Solar Power with battery backup for ESP32]

Comment: Provide Solar specs, datasheet, which is necessary to design over-voltage protection such as a Zener+transistor power shunt

Comment: It seems better to define what you expect for cost, complexity, power voltage tolerance, noise, and cooling if you expect to drop 1 to 2V @ 1A or 1 to 2W in linear mode.

Comment: Found a LDO voltage regulator with a Vin up to 25 volts; part number is Rohm BA033CC0WT.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Stewart for your comments and answering question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have a 6V PV rated at <=10W @ 5.7V but Voc= 6.7V based on your LDO rated for 1A @ 5V.

Very low dropout 1A LDO's tend to also have very low Vin max. and some great replacements from EXAR became obsolete but perhaps not profitable after the company buy-out.

There are still many good [alternatives.](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/pmic-voltage-regulators-linear/699?s=N4IgjCBcpgTAnFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG1wx4B2AVgAYQiAWADgGZrqQBdIgBwAuUEAGVBAJwCWAOwDmIAL5Fa1dkhCpImXIRLkQCWmFVMQ7erWbVWZ6s2O0zNZvXVEwbq7DOfW9nw8wADYGRA9mdlY3X1pjDlj4WGtfYLBmMG4PWnhWWkDweDZmZl8aTkYiWBMLJz4QIRFxaXklD3pQjS0dfCJSSAoIesbIEABJGUE8OTwJNvAuRGhNdGxe-QHDZnhMoYFhUebZBWVC1iWUVd0%2Bg0Zhg7FJY-nYDqdl7rW9fopq5OCzLAwgCqmoUlVoq8zOwwDCCjD2LB3IYaKxbER2Bk4tDQtRKuZQv5ePsmk9WopTj5NrQAG4AAiwABNSPUAcspIyRABaTwQEmjMyCACe-DwIgwOFQFKAA)

Of course the simplest solution is a Zener and emitter follower in a power NPN.